# How to convert txt file to ped and map file using plink?

Tags: plink

I am trying to convert a .txt and b.txt file to a1.ped and b1.map file using plink or R. I have read some manuals, but it seems that no one specifically mentions how to convert txt to ped and map.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: How about adding some tangible content? Show us what the files look like and what you expect

Comment: i want only change file format. I  need formats .ped and .map to encode genotypic data using convert.snp.ped function of GenABEL packages

Comment: The [tag:plink] that you have tagged is not the Plink the question is about. Choose different tags.